# Getting Serial Number of each computer in a list (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to get the serial numbers of a list of computers.
I have created a powershell script as follows:

---

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\pstest\computerlist.txt

Get-wmiobject win32_bios | ForEach-Object {$_.serialnumber}
```

---

All I get is as follows:

```
PS C:\pstest> .\pstest01.ps1
R6Z00180
```

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

The ComputerName parameter accepts a collecion of names so you can pass the content of the file to it:

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\pstest\computerlist.txt
Get-wmiobject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object __SERVER, SerialNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-WmiObject` has a `-ComputerName` parameter:

```
$computers | foreach { (Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -Computername $_).SerialNumber }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Shay's answer.
If you insist to have everything in a single pipeline:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\pstest\computerlist.txt) | 
Select-Object __SERVER, SerialNumber
```